# Internal Server Error when viewing a managed package in setup

Tags: managed-package, appexchange

When trying to view a managed package after selecting its name from the list of packages on the Packages page in setup we are receiving a lovely internal server error.

If anyone from Salesforce could provide some insight on this error that would be ever so helpful. Not being able to upload new packages, create patch orgs, and do push upgrades is sort of a big deal for an ISV.

The error number: 1275867465-12031 (1773998380)

Comment: This community will probably be of limited use for you. I'd suggest submitting a case so someone with access to the internal logs can help.

Comment: Yup, that's been done. Case # 11757931. I have a feeling this is not a simple Apex fix or the like. We deleted a custom tab from the package and then everything went broke.

Comment: I would also agree this community may not be ideal but this post by Josh Kaplan said to post details on GACKs here, https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/engineering/2015/02/gack.html